# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I am getting error when I try to get result of my stored procedure. which take two value from the c# desktop applications. I write this procedure for getting today date result

```
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@StartDate datetime,
@LastDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here
  SELECT * 
  from Visitor_Table 
  where Add_Date  BETWEEN @StartDate AND @LastDate
END
```

In my data base date store in following format `14/08/2014 5:18:23 PM` but when I try to get today result and pass value `14/08/2014` it show error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

I also try the value `14/08/2014 9:18:23` but problem is same. Please suggest me what is the way to get the result of today

Comment: "In my data base date store in following format" - why aren't you storing the values as `datetime` values? That would be a *much* better idea than storing them as strings...

Comment: Exactly. The main problem here is an abuse of a string data type as a data store instead of using the proper field type to start with. Fix that and the rest automatically gets sorted out AND is a lot faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT * from Visitor_Table where 
convert(varchar,Add_Date , 131) BETWEEN 
convert(varchar,@StartDate , 131)
AND  convert(varchar,@LastDate , 131)
```

[Bad Habits to Use Wrong DataTypes](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: So which datatype will use for storing date and time